# Java regular expression empty or my format

Tags: java, regex

Hello i have  a regular expression that works `[2-5][0-5]:[0-8][0-8]` accepts numbers like 20:88, 35:14, 32:54, etc.

I use the anotattion `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` to validate entities.

But I need to accept empty string or the format that I showed.

I tried `[^.]|[2-5][0-5]:[0-8][0-8]` `[^.]|([2-5][0-5]:[0-8][0-8])` 
`^.|[2-5][0-5]:[0-8][0-8]` `(^.)|[2-5][0-5]:[0-8][0-8]`

But not works. I tried put `empty|myformat`

Comment: is `16:29` correct value?

Comment: @Pshemo 1 OK, 6 not, : is OK, 2 Ok and 9 also OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:[2-5][0-5]:[0-8][0-8])?$
```

`(?:..)` is a non capturing group and `?` makes the group optional.

`^` and `$` are anchors for start and end of the string.

However, if your goal is to match a number between 20 and 55 for the first part and, 00 and 88 for the second part, then this pattern will do it better:

```
^(?:(?:[2-4][0-9]|5[0-5]):(?:[0-7][0-9]|8[0-8]))?$
```

Comment: Works, thanks, but why work, i not undertand first `?:`